# Why is the video description returned from the YouTube Data API truncated?

Tags: youtube-api

According to this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/aA-w-I0Eduo

I need to make an authenticated request to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads in order to get full descriptions. This works. However, when I add any API parameters in the URL the descriptions reverts back to the truncated form. e.g.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?orderby=published

Any ideas as to what I can do to put these parameters in the request and still get the full descriptions? Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's explained in [this blog post](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh_23.html); adding in those parameters changes your request so that it goes against the search index, which has truncated descriptions.

Comment: This link doesn't contain any information. Could you please provide updated info?

Comment: Updated the link to http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh_23.html